# How to access files on a USB stick after booting from that USB stick?

Tags: linux, usb-flash-drive, damn-small-linux, unetbootin

I booted computer from a USB stick using [UNetBootin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/unetbootin/) and [Damn Small Linux](http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/). Now I want to include some files on the stick such that they'll be available to me once the computer is booted up in Linux. I tried copying them into a directory at the top level of the stick's directory structure, but can't figure out how to access them from within Damn Small Linux.

How do I copy files onto my bootable stick such that I can access them?

Note: I'm open to using other tools from creating the bootable USB, so long as they'll help me access my files which are also on the USB.

Comment: Have you not just tried putting them in the 'Desktop' folder?

Comment: How do I put them in my Desktop? When I look at my USB stick, the only directories I see are boot/isolinux, KNOPPIX, and lost+found. None of these contain a "Desktop" directory for me to copy my files into.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to store files on a bootable USB stick with an OS you need to setup persistent storage when you originally create it then each time you boot into the USB OS files and settings from the previous session should be saved. See [these instructions](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/14912/create-a-persistent-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive/) on how to accomplish persistent storage on many different Linux distros.

You can also mount the hard drive (on most Linux distros) from the computer that you are using to run the USB OS and store them to a folder on the hard drive. So the next time you boot into the normal computer OS the files should be where you stored them and can grab them whenever you boot into the USB OS. However this option is not portable like the persistent storage option.

Comment: I'm not willing/able to use the hard drive from the computer as storage. Where can I find instructions telling me how to setup the persistent storage on the stick and get my files into persistent storage in the first place?

Comment: See edits above.

Comment: That's close to what I'm looking for. I was hoping to find something that would let me initialize the persistent storage with a set of files at USB creation time. Now that I have a better idea what I'm searching for (thanks to your help) I'll try Google to see if I can find something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I Know its late but this will help the next user.

- in Linux : These days most Linux distros include Disk Utility app. Select the live USB where you want to get the file (or where you booted from).
- At very bottom there should be a hyperlink " Mounted at_______"
- Click on that link and there you go.

Comment: I understand that you have nothing useful to do other than getting bothered by some1. But please try the method I am suggesting and they compare with the acceptable method.
I was in the same situation as OP, tried the acceptable method mentioned above there but I found there was simpler method to achieve the same which I wanted to share. 
Anyhow make yourself busy and it will be useful, Trust me.